# Avoiding non symbolic constants in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

One thing that often comes up in code reviews I participate in is 'magic numbers' inline in code as being a bad thing.

The preference is that a symbol be assigned somewhere.

Now what I am working with at the moment is in the QT sdk.  The class member `QButtonGroup.checkedId()` will return `-1` as a magic number to signify that there are no radio buttons in the group selected.

And if I write something like

```
if ( buttongroup->checkedId() == -1 )
{
   //yadda yadda
}
```

it will come up in the code review.

While certainly I can define a `const static int` symbol to give me that `-1`,  I'd much rather use something in the `Qt` namespace if it has a relevant constant defined.

Is there such a symbol already defined??

Comment: I don't know if it help but usually i use " < 0 " rather than " == -1". AFAIK, comparing to 0 is faster.

Comment: imo, `enum { INVALID_ID = -1 }` will be better than `const static int` solution. But has same disadvantage: you'll have to include file with definition wherever you use it. Comparing to zero is also a good option.

Comment: What policy does your company/organization have for handling magic numbers that come from external libraries? Note that many classes in Qt use -1 to signify "undefined", "error", etc. so QButtonGroup isn't the only one.

Comment: I usually add a anonymous namespace to the .cpp file and put a constant in there, but that is purely for a value that would only be used in that .cpp and nowhere else. If you are using the checkedId() calls elsewhere, you may want to move it out to some Utility header as a pre-defined constant?

Comment: I sort of avoided this particular issue, by opting to use `isChecked()` which will return a pointer to the (abstract )button checked, or zero.  So now I can compare to zero or `NULL`, that being an entirely different code review symbolic constant war.   NULL is enshrined in an internal coding standard, but 0 is enshrined in standards, places like for pure virtual.  But it has come up in the discussion

Comment: If you're feeling brave, try to get `nullptr` enshrined in your internal coding standard and deprecate `NULL`. That's a dedicated keyword in the language itself (from C++11 onward), designed to put an end to the `NULL` vs `0` war.

Comment: I know of projects that are frozen to using gcc set to use C++98 standard,  so I think that would be a tough fight.  I'm not even sure of the process to suggest revisions to the company standard, as it is a big company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such symbol is predefined; you would have to define it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Code reviews are about your code not the code of 3rd party libraries so you can't and shouldn't deal with it. Qt doesn't have any named entity to compare against so you have to compare the resulting code against `-1`. There is a bright side about it, though: `-1` is a broadly understood magic number so there should not be any misunderstanding — it is used in many different languages and libraries. However bad it is it is here and we have to live with it.

Comment: While this answer has more detail, @JonHarper was first,  so I'm giving this an upvote, but marked his answer correct because he answered correctly first.

Comment: @infixed: You won't hurt my feelings accepting the better answer. He gave a far better response. I up voted, too. ;-)

Comment: Speed counts too  :)   I mean this wasn't holding me up, but hypothetically speed can be valuable too